# How to find the probability of the number of data

Tags: probability, means, median

I have an exercise, i try to finish all of the question. I stack for the last one. Anyone can help me?
I attach the question.

I find the solution for (i) 2
(ii) 2.63 (iii) 0.055

And i need your help to solve the last one (iv). I guess we use probability formula to solve this question but i know which one of the number of favorable outcomes.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: It would help if you provided the questions...

Comment: I’m sorry because i am using cellphone. That’s why i only attach the question

Answer (score 0):

A favorable outcome here is when we picked one person who borrowed $6$ books and one person who borrowed some other number of books. By the multiplication principle, the number of favorable outcomes is equal to the product of: [the number of ways to pick one person from the people who borrowed $6$ books] times [the number of ways to pick one person from the people who borrowed other than $6$ books].

Comment: It means 1/13 x 1/187 = 0.0004. Is it true?

Comment: @J.Klins: No, that's not correct. My advice was to count the number of ways for the numerator, not probabilities yet. The numerator will be the number of all favorable outcomes -- NUMBER is an COUNTING, not fractions representing probabilities yet. The denominator then will be number of all possible ways to choose 2 people out of 200.